# Can this is code made more nice and correct of web scraping?

Tags: vb.net, web, web-crawler, web-scraping

Im trying to get school information of a site and want to save it as an excel tables sheet with details in each column, inital start was the below code help me in going further.
Column headers: school name, mascot, address, type, phone, fax etc. for a list of schools I have. For example I used one link.

```
Imports System.IO.StreamReader
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.maxpreps.com/high-schools/abbeville-yellowjackets-(abbeville,al)/home.htm")
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse

        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim rsssource As String = sr.ReadToEnd
        Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<h1 id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_Header"">.*</h1>")
        Dim r1 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_Mascot"">.*</span>")
        Dim r3 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_Colors"">.*</span>")
        Dim r4 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_GenderType"">.*</span>")
        Dim r5 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_AthleteDirectorGenericControl"">.*</span>")
        Dim r6 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<address>.*</address>")
        Dim r7 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_Phone"">.*</span>")
        Dim r8 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_Fax"">.*</span>")

        Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches1 As MatchCollection = r1.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches3 As MatchCollection = r3.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches4 As MatchCollection = r4.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches5 As MatchCollection = r5.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches6 As MatchCollection = r6.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches7 As MatchCollection = r7.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches8 As MatchCollection = r8.Matches(rsssource)


        For Each itemcode As Match In matches
            ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Value.Split("_").GetValue(4))
            ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Value.Split("><").GetValue(1))
        Next
        For Each itemcode As Match In matches1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Value.Split("_").GetValue(4))
            ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Value.Split("><").GetValue(1))

        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Anyway, yes, you can make it much nicer. First of all, you've imported the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace. You don't need to fully qualify `Regex`. Next, you can use *groups* in your matches.

Next, you can use a `WebClient` instead of all that `HttpWebRequest` clutter. Here's a start:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using wc As New WebClient()
            rssource = wc.DownloadString("http://www.maxpreps.com/high-schools/abbeville-yellowjackets-(abbeville,al)/home.htm")
        End Using

        Dim r  As New Regex("<h1 id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_Header"">(.*?)</h1>")
        Dim r1 As New Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_Mascot"">(.*?)</span>")
        Dim r3 As New Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_Colors"">(.*?)</span>")
        Dim r4 As New Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_GenderType"">(.*?)</span>")
        Dim r5 As New Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_AthleteDirectorGenericControl"">(.*?)</span>")
        Dim r6 As New Regex("<address>(.*)</address>")
        Dim r7 As New Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_Phone"">(.*?)</span>")
        Dim r8 As New Regex("<span id=""ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_Header_Fax"">(.*?)</span>")

        Dim matches As MatchCollection  = r.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches1 As MatchCollection = r1.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches3 As MatchCollection = r3.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches4 As MatchCollection = r4.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches5 As MatchCollection = r5.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches6 As MatchCollection = r6.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches7 As MatchCollection = r7.Matches(rsssource)
        Dim matches8 As MatchCollection = r8.Matches(rsssource)

        For Each itemcode As Match In matches
            'ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Value.Split("_").GetValue(4))
            'Use columns or something instead
            ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Groups(1).Value)
        Next

        For Each itemcode As Match In matches1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Groups(1).Value)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Next, consider giving your regular expressions meaningful names, making them `Static` and `Compiled` to increase efficiency, and not using regular expressions at all. Oh, and, use an HTML parser instead.